# Magento import products with custom attributes dropdown input

Tags: php, magento, import

I'm trying to programmatically import my products. Some of them have custom attributes. The attributes are already in magenta. How would I set them? I've tried the following things:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
$attribute->loadByCode( 1003, 'kleur' );   

$values = array();
$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
->setAttributeFilter( $attribute->getId() )
->setStoreFilter( Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, false)
->load();

foreach ($valuesCollection as $item) {
    $values[$item->getValue()] = $item->getId();
}

$simpleProduct->setData('kleur') = $data[6];
$simpleProduct->setkleur($data[6]);
```

But both aren't working. Note the attribute has a dropdown input type.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you should use Magmi to import your product.
Look here the wiki -> http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

If you want import automatically your product, you can with your crontab : 
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line

Comment: Please add the important bits from this links to your answer.